# Universal Image Loader crash when scrolling fast

Tags: android, android-gridview, filenotfoundexception, universal-image-loader

I am using nostra's [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), I am using it to load images on the gridview, with size of 100*100, but exception is raised WHEN scrolling really fast through grid view(just for demo, i have 13000 images on grid adapter), although the library handle the exception and user is not notified about it, below is the exception

```
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070): No such file or directory
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:145)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:612)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:607)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:536)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:371)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromContent(BaseImageDownloader.java:177)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:290)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:273)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:229)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-21 11:13:17.748: E/ImageLoader(2070):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Code in place are:

1. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is added
2. Both memory and disk cache
3. UnlimitedDiskCache for disk cache
4. Using latest library 1.9.2

That being said, the library crashes and no longer able to load the images and repeats all previous images, how to reset the library in such cases and start fresh, in-case of such crashes?

**Below is the configuration of ImageLoader**

```
String cacheDirectory=context.getCacheDir()+ImageLoaderConstants.IMAGE_CACHE_DIRECTOY_PATH;
        File cacheDir=new File(cacheDirectory);
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .delayBeforeLoading(0)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer())
        .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).threadPoolSize(5)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .memoryCacheExtraOptions(1280, 720) 
                .diskCacheExtraOptions(1280, 720,null)
                .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(5*1024*1024))
                .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) 
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .build();
```

**UPDATE:**

Adapter Code has nothing much,

```
imageLoader.displayImage(uriPath, holder.imgThumbnail);
```

I have all the configurations as defined in Usage section at [UIL GitHub](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: I recommended to use androidquery framework to use because it handle even "out of memory" error. http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: Is the memory cache option activated in your configuration?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia it is not OOM error

Comment: can you show your code for the adapter?

Comment: @Pork'n'Bunny that is not relevant

Comment: @Imtiyaz i have all the code implemented using universal and NO, i have not

Comment: @Akhil Jain: follow the link of Biraj Zalavadia.

Comment: @Imtiyaz i know what it is, i am aware of Picassio and aquery ,since i already have implementation in UIL, i am less willing to consider and aalso lot of customization options are available in this, then other

Comment: i have use picassio but universal image loader is more effective and more faster than any other.

Comment: @AkhilJain Please show your adapter's `getView()` code. Enable debug logging in configuration and show ImageLoader's logs after "crash".  Also add `resetViewBeforeLoading(true)` in display options.

Comment: @NOSTRA the adapter code has nothing much , i am only adding relevant code SEE UPDATE CODE,when set the image to the view, ok i will add `resetViewBeforeLoading(true)`

Comment: have you try to show thumb image of your original image?

Comment: @Haresh yes, many time it happens that user clears the thumb cache or thumbnail is not yet generated for that particular file/image and at that time, it becomes problem, since no file/uri found comes up.

Comment: please post your code ... adapter code.......whole activity also......

Answer (score 4):

One of my favorite library,

first of all please add

```
 DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .delayBeforeLoading(0)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
         .resetViewBeforeLoading(true) // add this line
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer())
        .build();
```

by adding this line image will not reflact when you scroll.

and second thing is, Check below links

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info

in that link read point no 8. stop loading when user scroll list/gridview.

```
boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
listView.setOnScrollListener(listener);
```

**Note:** Above code is just suggestion, i don't know it will solve your problem or not.